# Oozie Coordinator Timezone Issue

Tags: oozie-coordinator

Iam trying to schedule a worfkflow using oozie coordinator in Indian Timezone(UTC+05:30 hrs). So, I use (current time zone - 5:30 Hrs) to arrive at UTC time.
 However, the job does not run as expected. When the coordinator job is submitted, it takes different timings in HUE and job does not get completed on time. Kindly assist with the same.

FYI: I checked the HUE configration file(hue.ini) and timezone is set as UTC. Also, the oozie configuration file also has TIMEZONE = UTC(etc/oozie/conf/oozie-default.xml). Let me know what i am missing here.

Thanks,
 Vinoth

Comment: how exactly are you submitting the job execution time? are you submitting them in UTC?

Comment: Yes giving the time as UTC. Indian time 05:30 hrs ahead of UTC. So current time - 5:30 hrs is what I mention in oozie(through HUE).

Comment: @SQL.injection I have specified what I am doing through a document. Link is https://www.hightail.com/download/bXBhNWN1K3hkMnRYd3NUQw

Comment: @SQL.injection . I have specified scheduling using crontab ad now it is working fine as intended. However, while specifying the time directly, the frequency gets overriden as "0 0 * * *". This is actually causing the issue. You can also see the same in attachment mentioned in my previous post.

Comment: So it's not an issue with Oozie, _it's an issue with Hue_. I don't know which distrib you are using, but from personal experience with HortonWorks, I strongly advise you to forget about the Hue editor and "code" your Coordinators and Workflows in plain XML; then submit them with the Oozie CLI. Hue will just get you into trouble. Maybe Cloudera makes a better job of maintaining it, though.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter.. Thanks for the suggestion.. I will try my luck without HUE.